# How to capture tokens for a compiler

Tags: compiler-construction, token

I am working on a chunk of code while creating my own compiler. I am setting up a tokenizer that recognizes dim a[10], b[12] with tokens: a, b, 10, and 12

I am trying to have the function recognize a, 10, b, and 12 as the tokens with the below code:

```
  while (startPos < line.length()) {
   if (line[startPos] == '[' || line[startPos] == ']' || line[startPos] == ',') { 
      token[tokenNumber] = temp; 
      temp = "";
      tokenNumber++;
    }
    else {
      temp += line[startPos];
    }
    startPos++;
  }

  if (temp != "") {
    token[tokenNumber] = temp; 
    tokenNumber++; 
  }

  return tokenNumber;
}
```

currently, the tokens I am getting are correct, however, I am getting a blank token in between a[10], b[12] despite my preprocessor taking out all blanks.

How would I need to tweak my code in order to have the square brackets match up and accept a token when a right square bracket and comma is found?

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty easy to see why you would get a blank token for the comma: At the right bracket for `a[10]` you add a token, set the `temp` variable to blank, and then at the ',' you add the just blanket `temp` variable as a new token.

Why not just add the same guard in the loop against temp being empty as you have further down?